# Receiving an error when closing a window after closing the window that opens it

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently using tkinter to create a GUI for my program. When I open the export window, close the history window and attempt to close the export window, I receive the following error:

```
  File (filename), line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)

  File (filename), line 195, in close_export
    partner.export_button.config(state=NORMAL)

  File (filename), line 1637, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)

  File (filename), line 1627, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))

_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!toplevel.!frame.!frame.!button"
```

How would I go about fixing this?

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial   # To prevent unwanted windows

import random


class Converter:
    def __init__(self):

        # Formatting variables...
        background_color = "light blue"

        # In actual program this is blank and is populated with user calculations

        self.all_calc_list = ['0 degrees C is -17.8 degrees F',
                              '0 degrees C is 32 degrees F',
                              '24 degrees C is 75.2 degrees F',
                              '100 degrees C is 37.8 degrees F']


        # self.all_calc_list = []

        # Converter Main Screen GUI...
        self.converter_frame = Frame(width=300, height=300, bg=background_color,
                                     pady=10)
        self.converter_frame.grid()

        # Temperature Conversion Heading (row 0)
        self.temp_converter_label = Label(self.converter_frame, text="Temperature Converter",
                                          font=("Arial", "16", "bold"),
                                          bg=background_color,
                                          padx=10, pady=10)
        self.temp_converter_label.grid(row=0)

        # history Button (row 1)
        self.history_button = Button(self.converter_frame, text="History",
                                     font=("Arial", "14"),
                                     padx=10, pady=10,
                                     command=lambda: self.history(self.all_calc_list))
        self.history_button.grid(row=1)

        if len(self.all_calc_list) == 0:
            self.history_button.config(state=DISABLED)

    def history(self, calc_history):
        History(self, calc_history)


class History:
    def __init__(self, partner, calc_history):

        background = "#a9ef99"     # Pale green

        # disable history button
        partner.history_button.config(state=DISABLED)

        # Sets up child window (ie: history box)
        self.history_box = Toplevel()

        # If users press cross at top, closes history and 'releases' history button
        self.history_box.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW',
                                  partial(self.close_history, partner))

        # Set up GUI Frame
        self.history_frame = Frame(self.history_box, width=300, bg=background)
        self.history_frame.grid()

        # Set up history heading (row 0)
        self.how_heading = Label(self.history_frame, text="Calculation History",
                                 font="arial 19 bold", bg=background)
        self.how_heading.grid(row=0)

        # history text (label, row 1)
        self.history_text = Label(self.history_frame,
                                  text="Here are your most recent "
                                       "calculations.  Please use the "
                                       "export button to create a text "
                                       "file of all your calculations for "
                                       "this session", wrap=250,
                                  font="arial 10 italic",
                                  justify=LEFT, bg=background, fg="maroon",
                                  padx=10, pady=10)
        self.history_text.grid(row=1)

        # History Output goes here.. (row 2)

        # Generate string from list of calculations...
        history_string = ""

        if len(calc_history) > 7:
            for item in range(0, 7):
                history_string += calc_history[len(calc_history)
                                               - item - 1]+"\n"

        else:
            for item in calc_history:
                history_string += calc_history[len(calc_history) -
                                               calc_history.index(item) - 1] + "\n"
                self.history_text.config(text="Here is your calculation "
                                              "history.  You can use the "
                                              "export button to save this "
                                              "data to a text file if "
                                              "desired.")

        # Label to display calculation history to user
        self.calc_label = Label(self.history_frame, text=history_string,
                                bg=background, font="Arial 12", justify=LEFT)
        self.calc_label.grid(row=2)

        # Export / Dismiss Buttons Frame (row 3)
        self.export_dismiss_frame = Frame(self.history_frame)
        self.export_dismiss_frame.grid(row=3, pady=10)

        # Export Button
        self.export_button = Button(self.export_dismiss_frame, text="Export",
                                    font="Arial 12 bold", command=self.export)
        self.export_button.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # Dismiss Button
        self.dismiss_button = Button(self.export_dismiss_frame, text="Dismiss",
                                     font="Arial 12 bold",
                                     command=partial(self.close_history, partner))
        self.dismiss_button.grid(row=0, column=1)

    def close_history(self, partner):
        # Put history button back to normal...
        partner.history_button.config(state=NORMAL)
        self.history_box.destroy()

    def export(self):
        get_export = Export(self)


class Export:
    def __init__(self, partner):

        background = "#a9ef99"     # Pale green

        # disable export button
        partner.export_button.config(state=DISABLED)

        # Sets up child window (ie: export box)
        self.export_box = Toplevel()

        # If users press cross at top, closes export and 'releases' export button
        self.export_box.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', partial(self.close_export, partner))

        # Set up GUI Frame
        self.export_frame = Frame(self.export_box, width=300, bg=background)
        self.export_frame.grid()

        # Set up Export heading (row 0)
        self.how_heading = Label(self.export_frame, text="Export / Instructions",
                                 font="arial 14 bold", bg=background)
        self.how_heading.grid(row=0)

        # Export Instructions (label, row 1)
        self.export_text = Label(self.export_frame, text="Enter a filename in the "
                                                         "box below and press the "
                                                         "Save button to save your "
                                                         "calculation history to a "
                                                         "text file.",
                                 justify=LEFT, width=40, bg=background, wrap=250)
        self.export_text.grid(row=1)

        # Warning text (label, row 2)
        self.export_text = Label(self.export_frame, text="If the filename you "
                                                         "enter below already "
                                                         "exists, its contents "
                                                         "will be replaced with "
                                                         "your calculation history",
                                 justify=LEFT, bg="#ffafaf", fg="maroon",
                                 font="Arial 10 italic", wrap=225, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.export_text.grid(row=2, pady=10)

        # Filename Entry Box (row 3)
        self.filename_entry = Entry(self.export_frame, width=20,
                                    font="Arial 14 bold", justify=CENTER)
        self.filename_entry.grid(row=3, pady=10)

        # Save / Cancel Frame (row 4)
        self.save_cancel_frame = Frame(self.export_frame)
        self.save_cancel_frame.grid(row=5, pady=10)

        # Save and Cancel Buttons (row 0 of save_cancel_frame)
        self.save_button = Button(self.save_cancel_frame, text="Save")
        self.save_button.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.cancel_button = Button(self.save_cancel_frame, text="Cancel",
                                    command=partial(self.close_export, partner))
        self.cancel_button.grid(row=0, column=1)

    def close_export(self, partner):
        # Put export button back to normal...
        partner.export_button.config(state=NORMAL)
        self.export_box.destroy()


# main routine
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Temperature Converter")
    something = Converter()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Don't know if it will help but try changing `self.export_box = Toplevel()` to `self.export_box = Toplevel(partner.history_box)` inside the `Export` class.

Comment: Please post the full traceback. You seem to be missing some statements. Also, is all of this code really necessary to reproduce this problem? It seems like an awful lot of code for a fairly simple question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be explicitly changing the state of the button in the partner, but the partner has been destroyed. You should check that the button exists before trying to set the state.

```
def close_export(self, partner):
    if partner.export_button.winfo_exists():
        partner.export_button.config(state=NORMAL)
    self.export_box.destroy()
```